# GUIMiner not utilizing 2nd GPU

Tags: gpu, guiminer

I've just setup GUIMiner, I have two graphics cards, and they are both running. However, one is getting ~400 Mhash/s, the other is getting ~10 Mhash/s.
The monitoring of the GPU's also shows one running at 95%, the other at ~5%.

Is there an obvious reason for this?

Comment: I rebooted my machine, and now both GPU's are running at ~50%, with GUIMiner reporting speeds of ~200Mhash/s for both workers.

Comment: We don't use GPU miners today, the amount you can mine with one is many orders of magnitude below the sensible minimum output size of a Bitcoin transaction. They have been irrelevant for 3 years now, and support has been removed from all updated software.